# Passar uma informação para um Form submit

Tags: php, javascript

Eu havia feito uma pergunta mal elaborada. Eu gostaria de passar um informação por um form submit, essa informação seria padrão por exemplo:

> Senha = 123

Essa informação não iria aparecer para o usuário seria transmitido em background para eu fazer um post.

Eu tenho alguns inputs, por exemplo:

```
<div class="row" style="border:none!important;">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-xs-6 inline-input">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="elegant icon_phone"></span></div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control mask-phone" id="telefone-cadastro" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone" required>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

O que eu preciso e passar um informção como se fosse um input mas eu já iria setar o valor que era teria na hora do submit.

Comment: Queres setar no browser ou setar no lado do servidor?

Comment: Pelo que percebi "seria transmitido em background para eu fazer um post" deve ser no formulário certo?

Comment: Porque se quiseres setar no servidor o melhor seria usares uma session, pois no browser pode ser manipulado.

Comment: É verdade, se for preciso ter alguma segurança nesta operação deve guardar o valor também no lado servidor e fazer a verificação quando envia os dados

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode fazer um [input hidden](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden):

```
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="senha">
```

O valor deste input também é enviado com os restantes dados, mas não é visível na página.

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigado pela resposta

Comment: De nada @WilliamCézar, ainda bem que resolveu... Mas sublinho que se for preciso alguma segurança nesta operação convem guardar o valor do lado servidor também para verificar depois ([como o Sergio disse](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145500/passar-uma-informa%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-um-form-submit#comment300168_145500), sessões seria o melhor http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Neste caso aqui não necessita nenhum segurança, esses valores que estou passando é apenas para poder completar os dados requeridos, estou adicionado uma pagina a um sistema já pronto então não tenho tanta liberdade para mudar algumas coisa, mas isso que você me passou ajudou bastante muito obrigado.

Comment: Ok ainda bem então @WilliamCézar

Comment: só mais um coisinha cara , se não for incomodar muito, eu achei que tava dando certo mas os valores estão chegando nulos, eu deixei assim meu inputs :
'<input type="hidden" value="leet" nome="sobrenome" id=sobrenome-cadastro>'  eu tentei colocar isso dentro de um '<div class="form-grou´p>'  mas não adiantou, continua nulos.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Tem um erro no html: `<div class="form-grou´p>`, deve fechar assim `<div class="form-group">`, e  `...id="sobrenome-cadastro"...` e tem de aceder ao valor neste caso do lado servidor assim: `$_POST['sobrenome']` cujo o valor vai ser `leet`

Comment: Eu tenho um exemplo funcionando de um input desse :
'<form:input path="sobrenome" maxlength="100" size="60" id="sobrenome-cadastro" placeholder='SOBRENOME' cssClass="form-cadastro-home-pequeno required" tabindex="2"/>'

Mas o contrário desse eu ja passaria o valor e ele não apareceria , o form group esta certo no código , só esta errado aqui.

Comment: Deve estar a faltar algo, veja aqui um ex: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden @WilliamCézar